# difference between "in" and "during"

Tags: grammar

what's the difference between **in** and **during**? Which one is correct in the following sentence?

Here's the sentence :

- John's total business income ***during/in*** March is fifty-six thousand dollars.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Which preposition would be correct: "in" or "during" a time period?](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/271011/which-preposition-would-be-correct-in-or-during-a-time-period)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Both "in" and "during" are grammatical and idiomatic with respect to time. I must admit that I prefer to use "during" for time and "in" for space, but that may just be a personal idiosyncrasy of style.

In this specific case, however, I would probably prefer "for" if discussing income with respect to the entire month. But you will be understood and sound idiomatic with any of these prepositions.